# Restrict number of application users in Facebook app

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-canvas

Is it possible to limit the total number of user installs of a Facebook application using Facebook API or configuration?

Obviously the beauty of Facebook's platform is the virality. However, the greater the number of installations the more server demands grow etc.

So when building applications for clients with fixed budgets (think marketing activity / capping adverts per day based on spend) - is there a way to restrict the total number of users that Facebook allows to install an application?

Specifically talking here about building Facebook Games.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no build-in mechanism for that – because usually developers are *happy* about an ever-growing user base.

A canvas app is not really “installed”, users just *connect* to it. And this is the only point where you could try to handle this – once a user *has* connected to your app, you can recognize that (via the `signed_request` parameter or using the JS SDK) when he visits your app next time. So from a certain point on you could just not ask users for login any more (FB.login, redirecting them to the Auth dialog, …).

Obviously your initial app page will still be called, but any stuff you do afterwards with connected users and their data (if that’s what strains your little server most) you could just stop for users that are not already connected. Big downside of this is of course, if a user removes your app (willingly or by accident), they will find no way to re-connect with your app again.

---

Maybe you should consider hosting your app on a platform like Heroku – it’s free, and I think they will provide you with enough server power to handle your app growing larger than initially planned/expected.

Comment: Thanks CBroe, you answered the question early on. I get the point of FB virality as mentioned above and that we can authenticate against both our own users database and FB users.

I just wanted to know if Facebook API supports this. We have a large stack built on another cloud platform. The issue is matching fixed budgets against hosting provision which I think you may have missed.